# Android Studio - Reading local file - Permission denied despite having permission in Manifest file

Tags: android, permissions, filenotfoundexception

I'm trying to parse a local .xml file using XmlPullParseFactory. I'm having trouble accessing the path **"/storage/emulated/0/Download/testcards.xml"** despite having applied permission in the manifest file.

```
public void parseXML(){
    XmlPullParserFactory parserFactory;
    try{
        parserFactory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
        XmlPullParser parser = parserFactory.newPullParser();

        InputStream is = new FileInputStream(new File("/storage/emulated/0/Download/testcards.xml"));

        parser.setFeature(XmlPullParser.FEATURE_PROCESS_NAMESPACES, false);
        parser.setInput(is,null);

        processParsing(parser);
    } catch(XmlPullParserException e){

    } catch (IOException e) {

    }

}
```

My manifest file:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="demoapp1domain.demoapp1">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<application
.....
```

When I try to run my program I get:

java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Download/testcards.xml **(Permission denied)**

This is the code for getting the path:

```
public void startFileExplorer(View view) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    intent.setType("text/xml");   
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
    try {
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select your flashcards .XML-file "), REQUEST_CHOOSER);
    } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please install a File Manager.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_CHOOSER:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                final Uri uri = data.getData();
                String myXMLFilePath = uri.getPath();
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

**Any idea why permission is denied?**

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 26
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "demoapp1domain.demoapp1"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 26
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32635704/android-permission-doesnt-work-even-if-i-have-declared-it

Comment: Also would be advised to use the Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS instead of hardcoding the path. Your problem is you need to ask for the read permission at runtime because it is a dangerous permission

Answer (score 1):

Thanks CommonsWare and Alex, obviously you were right!
It works now that I ask for permission in runtime.

```
 String[] permissions = {Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};
        requestPermissions(permissions,PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
        InputStream is = new FileInputStream(new File("/storage/emulated/0/Download/testcards.xml"));
```